# How to replace value recursively in yq depend on key and value type?

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I wish I could use yq to iterate a yaml recursively, find all key-value pairs, whose key is `image` and value type is `string`(!!str), then add a prefix to the original value.

Input:

```yaml
serving:
  template:
    image: "docker.io/serving"
custom:
  template:
    image: 
      type: string
      description: "..."
eventing:
  image: "docker.io/eventing"
```

Add a prefix `private.io/` to all `image` field if its value type is `string`(!!str) recursively.

Expected output:

```yaml
serving:
  template:
    image: "private.io/docker.io/serving"
custom:
  template:
    image: 
      type: string
      description: "..."
eventing:
  image: "private.io/docker.io/eventing"
```

For a equivalent json, I can use the `walk` operator to do such thing:

```bash
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("image") and (.image|type) == "string" then .image = "private.io/" + .image else . end)' input.json
```

Is there any equivalent operator like `walk`, I have tried the `..` operator

```yaml
yq '.. | select(tag == "!!str" and key == "image") |= "private.io/" + . ' input.json
```

But this command add some entries to the yaml, result in:

```yaml
serving:
  template:
    image: "private.io/docker.io/serving"
custom:
  template:
    image:
      type: string
      description: "..."
eventing:
  image: "private.io/docker.io/eventing"
template:
  image: "private.io/docker.io/serving"
image: "private.io/docker.io/serving"
private.io/docker.io/serving
template:
  image:
    type: string
    description: "..."
image:
  type: string
  description: "..."
type: string
description: "..."
string
...
image: "private.io/docker.io/eventing"
private.io/docker.io/eventing
```

Any ideas or walk around ? Thanks, sincerely~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, and you almost had it. Just set parentheses to retain the context:

```bash
yq '(.. | select(key == "image" and type == "!!str")) |= "private.io/" + .'
```

```yaml
serving:
  template:
    image: "private.io/docker.io/serving"
custom:
  template:
    image:
      type: string
      description: "..."
eventing:
  image: "private.io/docker.io/eventing"
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) v4.31.1

---

Note: With [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) or [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) you can also use your original `walk` filter on your YAML input. Both tools can process YAML files using proper jq syntax.

```bash
yq -y 'walk(
  if type == "object" and has("image") and (.image|type) == "string" 
  then .image |= "private.io/" + . else . end
)'

# or

gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output 'walk(
  if type == "object" and has("image") and (.image|type) == "string" 
  then .image |= "private.io/" + . else . end
)'
```